# Cast to objectid failed for value when calling findOne and populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a Mongodb database using Mongoose with table structure similar to the one in the Group.js file listed below.  When my code hits the findOne call, I am receiving the cast error listed below:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ FirstName: 'John',\n  MiddleName: null,\n  LastName: 'Doe'\n  Address: '1234 Anywhere St.' }\" at path \"_id\"

**Group.js (model file)**

```
let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    FirstName: String,
    MiddleName: String,
    LastName: String,
    Address: String
});
let User = mongoose.model(‘User', UserSchema);

let GroupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: type: String,
    groupType: String,
    users: [UserSchema]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);
```

**GroupRepository.js (method call that gets the group with their associated user lists)**

```
findGroupPopulateUsers(paramList, cb){
        this.group.findOne(paramList).populate('users').exec(function (err, entity) {
            if (!err)
                cb(err, entity);
           else
                cb(err);
        });
    }
```

**Declaration for the group model before injecting into the GroupRepository class**

```
const user = require('../models/Group');
```

Here is the paramList I am passing in to the findGroupPopulateUsers method call

```
{"groupType": "free"}
```

I am confused about what is triggering this error?  I tried to follow the docs. on the mongoose website for handling subdocument population.  Please let me know what I am missing in the rules about how subdocuments should be populated?

Here is a weird thing I am noticing, so the subdocument seems to return and I don't get the error if I don't specify the ".populate(....)" method call.  However, if I try to access the "_id" field of the user subdocument, it keeps coming back undefined.

Comment: Can you add your paramList to your question?

Comment: Will do.  I will add to the bottom of the code section.

Comment: can you add one sample document for user and group schema?

Comment: Vijay What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add .lean() for findOne function.

```
this.group.findOne(paramList).populate('users').lean().exec(function (err, entity) {
       if (!err)
           cb(err, entity);
       else
           cb(err);
       });
```

Comment: The problem is still there after I try this.  I am still noticing that I don't get the error message when I remove the ".populate('Users')" call.  However, the "_id" field is not present in the user subdocument.

Comment: I thought the _id was autogenerated for each collection by default or is that excluding subdocuments?